# Linguex glosses and translation separating across page break

Tags: page-breaking, linguistics, linguex

I use `linguex` and I don't want my examples to be separated from their interlinear gloss and translation by a page break. Currently I have to check the PDF output and use the package `needspace`, but obviously this is a chore/bore.

```
\needspace{4\baselineskip}
```

Keeps the next 3 lines together.

Is there any way of telling LaTeX not to split `linguex` examples across two pages, ever?

Clarification: I don't want it to keep sub-examples a. b. c. together.

Edit: adding a new command such as in the response to [this same question in gb4e](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209228/using-gb4e-keeping-interlinear-glosses-together-on-the-same-page) is not a solution to this question - I have already stated that the solution should not involve returning to each example environment manually. The solution for `gb4e` is undesirable as it would involve finding each already written example, but also because it changes line spacing slightly to the old `gb4e` style. It also involves the addition of a command to each `linguex` example, making it a less than elegant solution to a global problem within the document's style. There might be a solution in adding the `\nobreak` command to the package somehow, but as of now, there is no solution.

What I mean is that a `linguex` example looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{leipzig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\glt{\nobreak}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5] 

\exg. y cath-od\\
{\Art} cat-{\Pl}\\
`the cats'

Some text about cats.

\end{document}
```

[image: normal example with linguex spacing]

whereas the solution proposed would be this:

```
\exg. y cath-od\\
{\Art} cat-{\Pl}\\
\glt `the cats'
```

[image: Proposed solution screenshot]

and I want my examples to stay as they were because 1) don't want to edit them all by hand 2) inelegant solution to a straightforward issue.

Comment: Since an example can have subexamples, are you only concerned about keeping example/glosse/translation together for any particular sentence or also keeping e.g. (1) a, b, c together?

Comment: Oh sorry yeah just the ex/gloss/trans

Comment: Since `gb4e` and `linguex` use the same glossing macros (`cgloss4e`) this is a duplicate.

Comment: @AlanMunn this is not a solution as `linguex` does not use a command for its translation line, meaning I would have to go in and change all the hundreds of `\exg.` examples manually, which I have already stated that I do not want to do. I was talking about having to insert `\needspace` manually, but `\nobreak` only offers a similar solution so I think it's clear that it is undesirable. Would it help if I showed the layout of a `linguex` example or should we assume respondents know the package basics?

Comment: Well a minimal example is always helpful.

Comment: (Your edit doesn't actually add a minimal example.) I'm sorry to say this, but this is a misuse of the glossing macros. What `linguex` should have done was define `\glt` to do whatever it liked and keep the markup. The spacing issue is just a matter of removing the `\vskip` from the definition of `\glt`. But `linguex` by design eschews markup and so as a result you have no way to know that the translation line *is* a translation line.

Comment: Also the spacing issue is true of using `\trans` in `linguex` examples too (iirc), so not just an issue of editing the newly defined command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43529/discussion-between-laua-and-alan-munn).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution to the problem which doesn't require the use of the `\glt` macro.  This will also work with `gb4e` (with the `\glt` macro), and I've added a combined answer to the linked (almost duplicate) question

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{linguex}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\gl@stop}{\nobreak}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\exg. wuz x̃ũch it-ak xohish-em\\
         1\textsc{sg.prn} bread eat-\textsc{inf} want.\textsc{prs}-1\textsc{sg}\\
          `I want to eat bread.'


\ex.    This is another example.

\end{document}
```